# There is extra background on my dialog view, how can I remove or manipulate it?

Tags: android, background, dialog, transparent

this is welcome_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/toast_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/dialog_background" >

<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/toast_detail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is dialog_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffffffff"
    android:endColor="#00000000"
    android:angle="45"/>
<padding android:left="20dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="20dp"
    android:bottom="0dp" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

The result is on top of another rectangular view which I could not manipulate. Sorry, I cannot post the result image as I am not yet allowed to post images.

I am trying to create a dialog countdown counter with a transparent background. I already tried several approaches but there is always that extra white background which I do not know where that view comes from. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

In my code with problems, I used alertDialogBuilder, and i think this is the view with background (correct me if I am wrong). I tried this line on this,  but it did't work:

```
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

Eventually, i found this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/
Rewrote my dialog creation and voila! I could remove the background with the line of code above.